# How to mock axios call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-testing-library, react-testing

I have a component Student component as follows

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Student(props) {
  const [studentRecord, setStudentRecord] = useState(props.stRecord);
  const [studentSubjects, setStudentSubjects] = useState(null);
  function getStudentSubjects() {
    let apicalladdress = '/studentapi/GetStudentSubjects/' + studentRecord.studentNumber;
    axios.get(apicalladdress).then((result) => {
      setStudentSubjects(result.data);
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudentSubjects();
  }, [studentRecord]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{studentRecord.studentNumber}</div>
      <div>{setStudentSubjects[0].subjectName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a test created as below

```
import {StudentSubjectsData} from "../globalDataProvider";
import AxiosMock from "axios"

it("make sure student renders",async ()=>{
  const mockStudentSubjects=await Promise.resolve({data: StudentSubjectsData()});
  AxiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue(mockStudentSubjects);
  
  render (<Student stRecord={StudentRecord}/>);
}
```

But I am getting following errors

Error 1. An update to Student component inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)
for line :setStudentSubjects(result.data);

Error 2. For following print line, I am getting error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading subjectName)

```
<div>{setStudentSubjects[0].subjectName}</div>
```

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see how you mock the `axios.get()` method, I will use `jest.spyOn()`  to mock it.

For the second error, the `studentSubjects` state is `null` for the first render. It's better to give an empty array instead of `null` as its initial value. Besides, you can use [optional chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access the value.

`Student.tsx`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export function Student(props) {
  const [studentRecord, setStudentRecord] = useState(props.stRecord);
  const [studentSubjects, setStudentSubjects] = useState<{ subjectName: string }[]>([]);
  function getStudentSubjects() {
    let apicalladdress = '/studentapi/GetStudentSubjects/' + studentRecord.studentNumber;
    axios.get(apicalladdress).then((result) => {
      setStudentSubjects(result.data);
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getStudentSubjects();
  }, [studentRecord]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{studentRecord.studentNumber}</div>
      <div>{studentSubjects[0]?.subjectName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Student.test.tsx`:

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react';
import { Student } from './Student';

describe('75502126', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const axioGetSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValue({ data: [{ subjectName: 'a' }] });
    render(<Student stRecord={{ studentNumber: 1 }} />);
    expect(await screen.findByText('a')).toBeInTheDocument();
    axioGetSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75502126/Student.test.tsx (8.98 s)
  75502126
    ✓ should pass (34 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Student.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.508 s
```

Comment: Thank you Lin Du, for pointing out the solution. I have accepted your answer. You have clarified on couple of things which I wanted. Only thing in the same issue I am having is I am still getting a message for this line "setStudentSubjects(result.data);" which says "when testing, code that causes react state update should be wrappered into act(...)
". Any suggestions here please....